# how to change to public

Tags: vb.net, properties, friend, public

```
Public Sub mainlogin_Authenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles mainlogin.Authenticate
    'Are the credentials valid?
    If Membership.ValidateUser(mainlogin.UserName, mainlogin.Password) Then
        'Has the password expired?
        Dim usrInfo As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(mainlogin.UserName)

        Dim daysSincePwdChange As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Subtract(usrInfo.LastPasswordChangedDate).TotalDays)
        If daysSincePwdChange > SecurityUtils.DefaultPasswordExpiryInDays Then
            'Password expired, send user to change password
            Response.Redirect("~/ChangePassword.aspx?UserName=" & Server.UrlEncode(mainlogin.UserName))
        Else
            e.Authenticated = True 'Credentials valid & password is current
        End If
    Else
        e.Authenticated = False    'Invalid!
    End If
end sub
```

but I got this error

> Error 6   'System.Web.SecurityUtils' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.

Comment: Remember to specify the programming language in the title and tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can't - as it says, `System.Web.SecurityUtils` is inaccessible. You can't make it public - it's not *designed* to be public. Change your approach so that you don't need it.

Of course, it could be that you really want to refer to a different type... were you reading [this page](http://www.worldofasp.net/News/ASP-NET/re-5736_ASP-NET-Membership-Tip--Requiring-New-Users-To-Change-Their-Password-When-Logging-On-For-The-First-Time.aspx) by any chance? My guess is that here, `SecurityUtils` is a different custom class, not `System.Web.SecurityUtils`.

All it's doing is getting a default expiry for the site though - and that's probably something you want to implement in your own way anyway. It's likely to just be a constant, or possibly something from a settings file. It's not like there's going to be a lot of logic there.